# Pivot table in Google Data Studio

Tags: pivot-table, looker-studio

I have such pivot table in Google Data Studio:

[image: pivot table]

How to write a formula to sum columns `Count1` and `Count2` in new a column:

```
SUMC1-C2
```

I have no idea how to do this. I tried to Add Metric or Add Column dimension and write there some formulas like `SUM(Count1+Count2)` or `Count1+Count2` simply. In any case I've got:

> Unknown dimension or metric ID: Count1

Comment: Can you please show us what you tried already? We are not here to write code for you but to help with concrete questions.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how do this. I try Add Metric or Add Column dimension and write there some formulas like SUM(count1+count2) or simply Count1+Count2. In any case I've got "Unknown dimension or metric ID: Count1"

Answer (score 2):

Using the sample data added based on the comments:

| id | datetime | counter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1124 | 2020-05-26 14:49:07 | C1 |
| 1164 | 2020-05-26 14:49:07 | C2 |
| 1163 | 2020-05-27 14:49:07 | C3 |
| 1124 | 2020-05-27 14:49:07 | C3 |
| 1165 | 2020-05-28 14:49:08 | C3 |
| 1166 | 2020-05-28 14:49:11 | C4 |
| 1167 | 2020-05-29 14:49:14 | C2 |
| 1168 | 2020-05-29 14:49:17 | C1 |
| 1169 | 2020-05-30 14:49:20 | C4 |

It can be achieved using a [Table](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7189044) with each Metric represented by an individual [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685), a [CASE](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) statement:

1. **C1**:

```
COUNT(CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(counter, "(C1)") THEN id
    ELSE NULL END)
```

2. **C2**:

```
COUNT(CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(counter, "(C2)") THEN id
    ELSE NULL END)
```

3. **C3**:

```
COUNT(CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(counter, "(C3)") THEN id
    ELSE NULL END)
```

4. **C4**:

```
COUNT(CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(counter, "(C4)") THEN id
    ELSE NULL END)
```

5. **C1PLUSC2**:

```
COUNT(CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(counter, "(C1|C2)") THEN id
    ELSE NULL END)
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/f5a6ea04-6c90-4d09-9bcd-8b96a5d96d3f/page/wvhRB) to and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]